# How to insert a new line above current in Webstorm?

Tags: webstorm

The equivalent behavior in Sublime Text and Visual Studio is "Shift+Control+Return."  and I would like to figure out a solution.

Either I can not find this in the documentation or no such functionality exists within Webstorm.

I suspect that one could create a macro to do this, but I can not figure out how to get the cursor position correct after execution.

Has anyone else found a solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the OSX edition of IntelliJ (just a beefed up version of WebStorm), there is a key binding called "Start New Line Before Current".  I think this is what you want.

Open up Settings -> Keymap -> Search for "line"

For me, it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

For you it might be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (instead of <kbd>Cmd</kbd>)

[image]